# The use of EOF (Ctrl + D) in getchar() in C

Tags: c, eof, getchar

I'm going through section 1.9 in K&R, I don't understand the use of EOF in the code implemented below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000            /* maximum input line length */

int mymygetline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print the longest input line */
int main()
{
    int len;                      /* current line length */
    int max;                      /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];           /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE];        /* longest line saved here */
    max = 0;

    while ((len = mymygetline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }
    if (max > 0)                  /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* mymygetline: read a line into s, return length */
int mymygetline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

What I tried:

- The initial program run well with difference line of input mark with "\n" is easy to understand
- When I tried to enter EOF firsttime inline, it just end recent input stream and set getchar() in waiting mode for input stream.

Question:

- When I enter EOF twice inline, does the first EOF just act like a "\n" or some other mechanism or I just missing something here.

Comment: Before you dive deeper into advanced topics, make it a priority to learn how to format your code with indentation and empty line to visually structure it. It's not only a matter of beauty, but helps yourself and the readers of your code to understand it much faster and also help to avoid errors.

Comment: Additionally, the use of **Ctrl + d** presumes you are using Linux, if that isn't the case, please specify the OS and compiler you are using. On Linux, **Ctrl + d** generates a manual `EOF` in your input buffer. Since your read-loop checks `(c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n'` as the test-clause, the loop will exit the first time it encounters an `EOF` (whether manually generated or when it exhausts the characters in `stdin`). So you run your program, e.g. `./myprog` and then press **ctrl + d**, the program should immediately exit.

Comment: @Hiểu Nam – In a sense, not only the first, but every _EOF just act like a "\n"_ (assumed by EOF you mean the key combination pressed, not the macro) - it causes the buffered input to be handed over from the OS to the program. An immediately following typed EOF just causes empty input to be handed over, and the library interprets this as the end of input.

Comment: The only time you should need a 2nd **ctrl + d** is if you accidentally enter another character before pressing **ctrl + d**, e.g.  `"dog[ctrl + d]"`. Then `EOF` is seen and `mymygetline()` returns a value `> 0` so it is called again. Now when you press **ctrl + d** on an empty line -- it immediately returns. For example if you type `"dog[Enter][ctrl + d]"` (where `[Enter]` is the Enter-key which generates the `'\n'` character) you will immediately exit when **ctrl + d** is pressed.

Comment: Bottom line is -- if the line isn't empty when you press **ctrl + d**, `mymygetline()` returns a value greater than zero and is called again.... requiring you enter **ctrl + d** again.

Comment: I'm using Kali Linux and gcc compiler. I've not cleared myself, I used the first EOF at the end of a line, if I don't enter the 2nd EOF, I can continue typing in inputs.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Ctrl-<D> works like this not only on Linux, but on macOS and other Unix-like systems, >99% of the most popular desktop and server systems (e.g. via SSH) not running Windows. In the Microsoft Windows command prompt, the key combination for EOF is Ctrl-<Z>.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason for my inquiry. @HiểuNam you don't use `EOF` at the ***END*** of the line, you use it at the beginning of the next line after you press `[Enter]`. (for this program) Obviously, you can press it whenever you like, but based on this program's logic, it is meant to be pressed at the beginning of an EMPTY line.

Comment: Aside: in `mymygetline()`, the `c == '\n'` test is invalid if `lim <= 1` because `c` is never initialized or assigned to in that case. Initialize `c` to 0 to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how a keypress propagates to your code (*mymygetline*()) function:

- The user presses the key.
- The keyboard receives the keypress and sends some kind of event containing the keycode to the Unix-like operating system.
- The operating system figures out that the event should be routed to a terminal (this includes terminal emulator windows on a GUI). The operating system converts the event to a byte sequence and sends it to the terminal.
- The terminal may do some more transformations and buffering. By default, it buffers (i.e. doesn't let through) bytes until a newline or something special (such as the character corresponding to Ctrl-*D*) is received.
- The libc code (called by getchar(3)) in the program reads a sequence of bytes from the terminal. While the terminal is buffering, the libc code blocks in the read(2) system call. As soon as the terminal flushes, read(2) receives many bytes at once, typically an entire line followed by a newline character, or an EOF indicator (read(2) returns 0).
- Your code (*mymygetline*()) receives the bytes read by read(2) one byte at a time from getchar(3). As soon as no more bytes are available, libc code calls read(2) again, which blocks until more bytes come.

If the user presses Ctrl-*D*, read(2) returns the bytes buffered so far (if any), a subsequent read(2) (triggered by the second Ctrl-*D*) returns 0, which causes getchar(3) to return EOF.